# Javascript functions disappear when JQuery is turn on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following strange behavior. The function func() must be called when input content is changed. This not working as long as JQuery is included in the document. Does anyone has an idea ? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function func()
            {
                alert();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id = "A" name= "A" onchange="func()" value = "0"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: close the script tag correctly: `<script>https://ajax.goog...</script>`

Comment: @ottrob which is still wrong but you had the right idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**script** is not a self enclosing tag. You have a mistake on your html: close your script tag of jQuery src.

Check this snippet:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function func() {
      alert();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="A" name="A" onchange="func()" value="0" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need close all script tags :)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function func()
        {
            alert();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my bad, I was not looking at the right section of the code. Thanks for help. Solved.